# How to get project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath in custom gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy

I want to create gradle plugin which will add additional task with type **JavaExec**

I have plugin:

```
class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {

    project.task('generate', type: JavaExec) {
      main = 'some.package.ClassWithMainInTestScope'
      args = ['some', 'arguments']
      classpath project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    }
  }
}
```

And i've got following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/pompei/IdeaProjects/greetgo.depinject/greetgo.depinject.gradle/build/test_projects/pr-20180720-164840-381-109260619/test/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'kz.greetgo.depinject.plugin']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'kz.greetgo.depinject.plugin']
   > Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for root project 'test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Qustion is: how can i get **project.sourceSets** in plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
    final JavaPluginConvention javaPlugin = getProject().getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class);
    final SourceSetContainer sourceSets = javaPlugin.getSourceSets();
    final SourceSet smoketest = sourceSets.findByName("smoketest");
    this.testClasspath = smoketest.getRuntimeClasspath();
```

Answer (score 1):

It works!!!

I do like this:

```
project.task('generate', type: JavaExec) {
      doFirst {
        def javaPluginConvention = project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention)
        classpath javaPluginConvention.getSourceSets().findByName("test").getRuntimeClasspath()
      }

      main = 'some.package.ClassWithMainInTestScope'
      args = ['some', 'args']
    }
```

And all OK!